# Looping through records

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, while-loop

I have a table where, among others, these three columns below are included. These are ID changes saved in the DB, where an ID in this case has gone from 1->2->3->4.

```
oldID    | newID   | added  
1        | 2       | 2012-11-23  
2        | 3       | 2012-11-24  
3        | 4       | 2012-11-25 
4        | 1       | 2012-11-26
```

What I would like to do is to send in a `oldID` parameter and return the `newID`, stepping through the changes. So for example, if I send in `2` it returns `1`.

I'm not getting anything with my SQL-query below because I don't really know what I'm doing.

```
DECLARE @dateCurrent datetime
DECLARE @datePrevious datetime
DECLARE @oldID int
SET @dateCurrent = '1970-01-01'
SET @datePrevious = '1970-01-01'
SET @oldID = '2'

WHILE (@dateCurrent >= @datePrevious)
    BEGIN
        SELECT @oldID = newID, @datePrevious = added
        FROM theTable
        WHERE oldID = @oldID
    END
```

Comment: Any approach that "changes IDs" is doomed

Comment: I agree with @Bohemian this is a bug fest. Use an immutable key on the data, Then have a look up Table (think of it like versioning) to find the immutable from the mutable key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree this might not look like the best solution, but I'm not about to change something in a system that has been running since 95'.

I got it to work like this:

```
DECLARE @dateCurrent datetime
DECLARE @datePrevious datetime
DECLARE @oldID int
SET @dateCurrent = '1970-01-01'
SET @datePrevious = '1970-01-01'
SET @oldID = '2'

WHILE (@datePrevious <= @dateCurrent )
BEGIN
SET @datePrevious = @dateCurrent 
SELECT @dateCurrent = t2.added, @oldID = t1.newID
from theTable
     inner join theTable t2
     on t2.oldID = t1.newID
     where t1.oldID = @oldID 
END
SELECT @oldID
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to recurse, you can use common table expressions

eg:

```
;with cte as 
(
select *, 0 as level from yourtable
union all
select t1.old, cte.new, t1.dateadded, level + 1 from yourtable t1
    inner join cte on t1.new = cte.old
    and t1.dateadded<cte.dateadded
) 
    select old, new from 
    (select old, new, ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by old order by level desc) rn from cte)
    v 
    where rn=1
```

Comment: Hmm, I might not have explained it good enough. If I send in `2` with this I'll get the first row in the table, but I want the last row. I would have thought I needed to join iteratively? Say the last row read `4 | 5` in which case I want `5` as output.